# Spring controller tests with mocks

Tags: spring, unit-testing, testing, controller

So I'm having some issues coming up with a solution for a test.

This is the method I want to test(I'm new to this). It clears all fields on a web page each time it's loaded.

```
@RequestMapping("/addaddressform")
public String addAddressForm(HttpSession session)
{
    session.removeAttribute("firstname");
    session.removeAttribute("surname");
    session.removeAttribute("phone");
    session.removeAttribute("workno");
    session.removeAttribute("homeno");
    session.removeAttribute("address");
    session.removeAttribute("email");

    return "simpleforms/addContact";
}
```

and here's what i have so far for the test

```
package ControllerTests;

import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator.Attribute;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpSession;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration (classes = {SimpleFormsControllerTest.class})

public class SimpleFormsControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void addAddressForm_ExistingContactDetailsInForm_RemovalFromSession()          throws     Exception{

    MockHttpSession mockSession = new MockHttpSession();

    mockSession.putValue("firstname", "test");
    mockSession.putValue("surname", "test");
    mockSession.putValue("phone", "test");
    mockSession.putValue("workno", "test");
    mockSession.putValue("homeno", "test");
    mockSession.putValue("address", "test");
    mockSession.putValue("email", "test");

    mockMvc.perform(get("simpleForms/addaddressform").session(mockSession));
}
```

As this is the first time I've ever had to do this kind of thing I don't have much clue where to go with this.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have to do is only assert the values, e.g.:

```
assertNull(mockSession.getAttribute("firstname"));
```

If you want to make sure it is the case, you can do:

```
assertNotNull(mockSession.getAttribute("firstname"));
```

before you fire the GET request.

Comment: Once i do that the tests fails as it still returns "test"